# WinLDAP custom server certificate authentication

Tags: winapi, ldap

I am trying to write a C++ program that uses WinLDAP for Active directory authentication; and currently trying to set a custom server certificate verification method (i.e. by setting LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE option in ldap_set_option() method)

The VERIFYSERVERCERT callback does not have a application specific data argument which i require to access other parameters in the application.

Is there a method (such as a ldap_set_option option) that i can use to keep a application related parameter bound to the PLDAP session handle?